# Import-CSV where date-column -lt/-gt (dd.MM.YYYY)

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am working on a small PowerShell script to process CSV files.

*CSV-file example:*

```
"lastname";"firstname";"birthday"
"meier";"bernd";"23.06.1976"
"hoffmann";"sven";"12.04.1955"
"berger";"tim";"14.15.2007"
```

The script creates a window where the user can select a date with two datapickers and so the user should able to remove all rows where the birthday is before or after the selected date.

```
Function Start-MyImport {
    #Build the GUI
    [xml]$xaml_ar = @"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="Title" Height="164.653" Width="498.907" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="464*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Name="agerange_go" Content="go!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="334,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <CheckBox Name="agerange_before" Content="birthday before:" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="agerange_after" Content="birthday after:" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <DatePicker Name="dp_before" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="176,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <DatePicker Name="dp_after" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="176,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

    $reader_ar = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml_ar)
    $Window_ar = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader_ar)

    $xaml_ar.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | ForEach {
        Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Window_ar.FindName($_.Name)
    }

    #Events
    $agerange_go.Add_Click({
        if ($agerange_before.IsChecked) {
           $dp_before = $dp_before.Text 
           if ($dp_before -ne "") {
                Write-Host $dp_before
                Import-Csv my.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 | 
                    where birthday -as[DateTime]::ParseExact($_."birthday", "dd.MM.YYYY", $null) -lt $dp_before | 
                    Export-Csv CsvFileOut.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInfo
           }
        }
        $Window_ar.Close()
        #Lieferant-Repl
    })
    $Window_ar.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
}

Start-MyImport
```

The problem is, that I can not parse the birthday column into a date. My way do not work.

```
where birthday -as[DateTime]::ParseExact($_."birthday", "dd.MM.YYYY", $null) -lt $dp_before
```

How is the right way to handle this?

Comment: IIRC in the date format only the month is uppercase, did you try "dd.MM.yyyy" ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to read and pay attention to the error message. (And, by the way, show us the error message. Don't just say that it doesn't work. That isn't helpful.)

```
C:\> [DateTime]::ParseExact("23.06.1976", "dd.MM.YYYY", $null)
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

So one of the two strings is wrong. The date looks okay, so that means we should take a look at the [format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), and indeed we find out that there is no such thing as "YYYY". If we correct it to "yyyy", then it works:

```
C:\> [DateTime]::ParseExact("23.06.1976", "dd.MM.yyyy", $null)

Wednesday, 23 June 1976 12:00:00 AM
```